# How to extract comparable results from TukeyHSD test (after two-way ANOVA) in R?

Tags: statistics, anova, posthoc, statistical-test, tukey

I did a two-way ANOVA test and ran a post-hoc Tukey test in R. I also extracted the significant rows from the post-hoc test.

My question is: is there a way to select only the rows that are comparable (at least one of the two independent variables matches)?

Using my data as an example, I am comparing differences between months and sites. Detected significance is only meaningful if one of the two IV's remains the same. Hence, even significant difference is detected between two sites at two different times, it wouldn't have any meaning (e.g. row 6, , 9, 11, etc.).

Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
pr2 <- structure(list(month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", 
    "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "May", "May", "May", "Jan", 
    "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", 
    "Apr", "May", "May", "May", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", 
    "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "May", "May", "May"), site = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("port", "bluff", "palme"
    ), class = "factor"), o2sq = c(0.779603911011558, 0.649472490663795, 
    0.71648014561332, 0.725992787199382, 0.716697608608313, 1.15854615763553, 
    0.606370304873445, 0.57764553510002, 1.06438465995301, 0.587898781427488, 
    0.793056685711943, 0, 0, 0, 0.996022820856577, 0.691613413638031, 
    0.886760916957465, 0.960916531324815, 1.08631189461523, 0.789106383079291, 
    0.77592897789954, 0.801976841325736, 0.769771561419952, 0.927750892886446, 
    0.813515300363769, 0, 0, 0, 0.152012700325758, 0.181681000115634, 
    0.214502617390993, 1.36038184365007, 0.938657806964214, 0.77488803531131, 
    0.811080573774404, 0.648324268012982, 0.773210264384908, 0.202464680801663, 
    0.183204457007831, 0.773247023777561)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 31L, 
    32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), class = "data.frame")

pr_aov2 <- aov(o2sq ~ month*site, pr2)
summary(pr_aov2)

TukeyHSD(pr_aov2) %>%
  tidy() %>%  #library(broom)
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(adj.p.value <0.05)
```

[image: Filtered significant rows]